# ProcessingJS modify stroke-width in SVG

Tags: svg, processing, stroke

I would like to dynamically set the stroke-width of an SVG curve from within a ProcessingJS sketch.

So far, the only solution that I have found is to use disableStyle() on the SVG shape and then manually set all of the style attributes like Fill(), stroke(), strokeJoin() and strokeWeight(). However, the opacity of the line seems to render differently when executed this way.

Is there some way to access and modify only the stroke-width and leave the other styles unchanged?

Here is the code that I have so far.  It seems to work okay, but it would be nice not to have to manually reset all the style attributes that were in the original svg file.

```
/* @pjs preload="frog_trajs.svg"; */
PShape trajs;
float zoom_factor = 1.0;
float imgW;
float ingH;
float lineWeight = 1.00;

//panning variables
float centerX;
float centerY;

boolean active = false;

PFont f;

void setup() 
{
  size(900, 600);
  frameRate(20);

  centerX = width/2;
  centerY = height/2;


  trajs = loadShape("frog_trajs.svg");
  trajs.disableStyle();

  imgW = trajs.width;
  imgH = trajs.height;


}

void draw() 
{
  background(255);

  //here, the styles are reset, with lineWeight dynamically updated by mouseScrolled()
  shapeMode(CENTER);
  strokeJoin(ROUND);
  strokeWeight(lineWeight);
  stroke(#EF25B2,170);
  noFill();

  shape(trajs,centerX,centerY,imgW,imgH);

}

void mouseScrolled()
{
  if(active){
   if(mouseScroll > 0)
   {
       //zoom out;
       zoom_factor = 1 - mouseScroll*0.01;

   }
   else
   {
      //zoom in;
      zoom_factor = 1 - mouseScroll*0.01;

   }

   lineWeight = lineWeight/zoom_factor;

  }
}

void mouseOver(){
   active = true; 
}

void mouseOut(){
   active = false; 
}
```